# How to recursively unzip using powershell function

Tags: powershell, recursion, unzip

I have single or multiple zip files at this location `C:\Temp\unzipped_files\`

I have a function that takes `$workspace` parameters like below:

```
Function RecursiveUnzip($workspace) {
    $outputDir = "$workspace\unzipped_files"
    $zips = Get-ChildItem -Path $outputDir -Filter "*.zip"

    foreach ($zip in $zips) {
        $markerFile = "$($zip.FullName).processed"

        if (Test-Path -Path $markerFile) {
            Write-Host "Skipping already processed ZIP: $($zip.FullName)"
        } else {
            Expand-Archive -Path $zip.FullName -DestinationPath $outputDir -Force
            Set-Content -Path $markerFile -Value "Processed"
            $nestedZips = Get-ChildItem -Path $outputDir -Recurse -Filter "*.zip"

            foreach ($nestedZip in $nestedZips) {
                RecursiveUnzip -workspace $workspace
            }
        }
    }
}

$wspace = 'C:\Temp'
RecursiveUnzip -workspace $wspace
```

I am required to pick each *.zip inside `C:\Temp\unzipped_files\` and keep unzipping each .zip file until no .zip is left that has not been unzuppied under `C:\Temp\unzipped_files\`.

Note: the .zip being extracted may have other .zip inside them which also needs to be unzipped.

My attempt above partially unzips but does not unzip those .zip files which sit inside other `.zip` files.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: What version of powershell are you using? `-PassThru` comes in quite handy in this case but only exists in pwsh 7+

Comment: Have you stepped through this with a debugger such as VS Code to see if it recognizes .zip files in the `$outputDir`?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon i have PS version 5.1

Comment: Does the recursive call need to be changed to `RecursiveUnzip -workspace $outputDir`?

Comment: @lit it does becoz i see the `<zipname>`processed` file created and gets unzipped too. The issue is that it does not recursively unzip those that are within the parent zip.

Comment: @lit i need everything all the zips and zips within extracted in one single folder whichever it be

Answer (score 1):

The following would be able to expand archives recursively and be compatible with PowerShell 5.1. PowerShell 7+ offers the [`-PassThru`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?view=powershell-7.4#-passthru) switch which can be used to simplify this task.

**NOTE:** The code will expand the nested Zip archives using their parent directory as destination to avoid collision.

```bash
# tweak this value if you want to overwrite (change to `$true`)
$overwrite = $false

$queue = [System.Collections.Generic.Queue[hashtable]]::new()
$queue.Enqueue(@{
    # using a relative path to target the zip, change this value accordingly
    LiteralPath     = Convert-Path .\pwshbinary.zip
    # using `pwd` to extract, change this value accordingly
    DestinationPath = Join-Path $pwd myDestination
    Force           = $overwrite
})

while ($queue.Count) {
    $current = $queue.Dequeue()
    Expand-Archive @current
    $hasZips = $current['DestinationPath'] | Get-ChildItem -Filter *.zip -Recurse

    foreach ($zip in $hasZips) {
        $queue.Enqueue(@{
            LiteralPath     = $zip.FullName
            DestinationPath = Join-Path $zip.DirectoryName $zip.BaseName
            Force           = $overwrite
        })
    }
}
```